# PHP errors with Joomla 3.1.5, SJ template and YT framework

Tags: joomla, php

While using Joomla 3.15 with **SJ template** with **YT framework**, I am getting the following errors:

```
Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in C:\xampp\htdocs\global\plugins\system\yt\includes\libs\yt-minify.php on line 120

Strict Standards: Non-static method JSite::getMenu() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\htdocs\global\plugins\system\yt\includes\site\lib\yt_template.php on line 107

Strict Standards: Non-static method JApplication::getMenu() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\htdocs\global\includes\application.php on line 593

Strict Standards: Non-static method JSite::getMenu() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\htdocs\global\plugins\system\yt\includes\site\lib\yt_template.php on line 107

Strict Standards: Non-static method JApplication::getMenu() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\htdocs\global\includes\application.php on line 593
```

I also installed the YT framework but I'm still still getting these errors.

Answer (score 0):

This is the result of the PHP error reporting.

Some Joomla extensions contain coding issues, some more subtle than others and those trigger `Strict` and `Notice` messages (and sometimes even worse).

I will show 2 ways of dealing with this type of issues:

### Editing php.ini

You can handle this by telling the PHP engine to hide those messages by editing the following directive in your `php.ini` file:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT
```

### Using the Joomla! admin configurations

You can also change the directive from the Joomla UI (the following is taken from Joomla! 3.1.5):

1. In the Joomla! admin interface, go to `System > Global Configuration`.

   [image: Global Configurations menu in the Joomla! admin panel]
2. Switch to the `Server` tab, Select 'None' in the `Error Reporting` box and click `save`.

   [image: The Server tab in the Joomla! global configuration]

This will remove all of the PHP error messages, so now you will have to rely on the logs to detect problems.

It is the recommended configuration for production, as error reporting is useful during development and testing.